# how to use only annotation mapping in doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

-Is there a way to make doctrine neglect or don't look in **entityxx.orm.xml** mapping files and look only in annotation mapping in the entity class?

-I'm getting error when try to modify an entity without modifying it's underline xml mapping too so i have to modify both!,actually my entities was imported from database but now it's converted to annotation and i don't want to use xml any more .

Comment: Just delete the xml files.

Comment: when i do i got mapping error i hope it is that simple !

Comment: That implies that your annotation mappings are messed up.  Nothing to do with the xml files.  Doctrine 2 / Symfony 2 only allows one type of mapping per bundle. If you have both xml and annotations then neither are used.  So focus on fixing your annotation mappings or use the xml files.  But you can't use both.

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible to use 2 differents method mapping for entity in symfony. Xml or annotation but not both in the same time.

You must delete xml mapping file if you want to use a annotation mapping.